# How to simulate a swipe on click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, hammer.js

I am currently trying to develop an app with some card swipe actions (similar to the way Tinder works).

I found a boilerplate which works pretty well in my current code :
https://www.cssscript.com/card-carousel-tinder/

The problem is : swipe actions can be fairly sluggish on old mobile devices (probably due to the continuous touch detection of hammer.js)

So, I wanted to add in a functionnality to change cards simply by tapping the card. 
The boilerplate has a tap detection function which is great, but I can't manage to simulate a swipe from a tap.

I have tried inputing custom finger coordinates from the function, but it just doesn't have any effect on the card (the fake touch is not detected)

https://www.cssscript.com/card-carousel-tinder/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will not animate the cards, but it will add a "like" and "dislike" button. When a user makes a selection, the card disappears and shows the next one.

At the bottom of push(), add (used jQuery here):

```
            $('<div class="swipe-right-button">Like</div>' +
              '<div class="swipe-left-button">Dislike</div>').appendTo(card)
```

At the top of onTap(e), add:

```
            let clickedElementClass = e.target.className;
            if(clickedElementClass.includes('button')) {
                if(clickedElementClass.includes('swipe-right')){
                    alert('clicked swiped right button')
                    // do something
                }
                if(clickedElementClass.includes('swipe-left')){
                    alert('clicked swiped left button')
                    // do something
                }
                this.board.removeChild(this.topCard)
                this.push()
                this.handle()
            }
```

You can style your buttons how you please. Here's an example:

```
            .swipe-right-button{
                background-color: #d7e2b7;
                width:50%;
                float: left;
                text-align: center;
                padding: 10px 0 10px;
            }
            .swipe-left-button{
                background-color: #eab4b4;
                width:50%;
                float: left;
                text-align: center;
                padding: 10px 0 10px;
            }
```